# Book Recommendation for Graphical Models and Bayesian Networks, good for self-study (meaning problems and solutions)

Tags: machine-learning, references, graphical-model, bayesian-network

I am watching some of the videos from the Stanford CS 221 course, which goes over issues including Bayesian Networks and Graphical models. There are models where I am trying to learn the joint distribution over all of the variables/nodes in a directed acyclic graph. In some cases, these are markov networks, in which case the edges are undirected.

The problem is that most of the books I have found don't have solutions to the problems. For example, the main books on these topics are the Daphne Koller book on *Probabilistic Graphical Models*, or the Murphy or Lauritzen books. But none of these books have solutions. And I would really like to practice applying these sum-product algorithms or variable elimination algorithms where I can see the solutions--so that I know I did things correctly.

Does anyone know a good resource on this topic that has problems and solutions for these types of models?